# Please, help me to convert shell-script to python

Tags: python, file, list, dir

I'd like to make python-script to search file by pattern in directory and show result. 
In shell it's easy and was made in an hour.

```
date=`date +%F`
path=/root/bkp
for i in $(ls $path)
do
str=`find $path/$i -name “*$date*.txt”`
if [$str]
    then
        echo “File in $i is OK”
    else
        echo “File in $i is not found”
fi
done
```

In Python

```
import subprocess,os,datetime,fnmatch
path='/root/bkp'
date=datetime.date.today()
pattern=str('%s' %date)
def find_file():
    obj=re.compile(pattern)
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
        match=obj.search(f)
            if match:
                print ‘File in ??? is OK’ ===== # need directory mention
            else:
                print ‘no file’
find_file()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by the question, but if you are just looking for if the filename has the pattern in it then you were pretty much there already.

edit: to recursively go through each directory

```
import os,datetime
path = "C:\\Temp"
date=datetime.date.today()
pattern=str('%s' %date)
filefound = False
def find_file(currpath):
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(currpath):
        for files in filenames:
            if pattern in files:
                print("File found in " + currpath)
                global filefound
                filefound = True
                return
        for directory in dirnames:
           find_file(path+"\\"+directory)
find_file(path)
if filefound == False:
    print("File containing " + pattern + " not found in " + path)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but apparently I was not clear enough. There are subdirectories in directory - /root/bkp:
/root/bkp/one 
/root/bkp/two
/root/bkp/three

There are files named by date, e.g 2013-02-04.txt, 2013-02-04.txt, 2013-02-05.txt in each subdirectory. 
So script should check whether file exists in subdirectory or not. File is named according date.today.
If it exists it prints something like-"File in [subdirectory] exits!"
If not it prints - "Oops! No file in [subdirectory]"

My shell script above works fine. Now I want to make my python script do the same.